# How to disable print function and readonly file in iframe using MVC4 C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

May i know how disable print function and readonly file in iframe ? kindly advise thank you. After lots of effort i was unable to disable pdf toolbar on browser.  here is my code if anyone have any idea then please let me know.

```
<div id="pdf1" >
<iframe id="form-iframe" src="@Url.Action("GetPDFFile")"></iframe>


</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var myPDF = new PDFObject({
           pdfOpenParams: {          
            toolbar: false,          
        }
    }).embed('pdf1'); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/209078/Disable-PDF-Save-and-Print-Button try to fins solution on this page

Comment: Please post the link as a comment or explain the solution in your post

Comment: Please keep link to original article but also provide a summary here. Link-only answers may be broken if link become unavailable (and they're often downvoted for that).

Comment: Nup it doesnt help me, even at this site it is clearly written that this is not feasible... is it nt feasible really